# how to create custom post type with templates

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am working on a project that requires a custom post type.
I am also required to have a breadcrumb that works with all types of post/page types.

The thing is that I haven't figured out a good way to achieve to have a custom post type that has a "startpage" and then some child pages.

in my world, i would like to set up a regular page (let's call it "cars") that I link to a template. The template should be somehow connected to the custom post type so when I create a post in custom post type (let's call it "BMW") and goes to that post, I want the website to be like http://test.com/cars/BMW.

The other problem here is that when I am on the page http://test.com/cars/bmw and what to run a function to see what my page ancestors the BMW page has, I get null because Wordpress recognise the BMW page as a post and cars as a page.

I don't know if you guys understand what I mean here but what is your best way to achieve a complete chain with custom post type so I can access or recognize all pages/post in the chain. Also, this is mostly for the breadcrumbs to work and I want that standard first-page "cars" in this chain so one can write content in the standard WYSIWYG that will appear on the site.

Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

When you register the post type, you specify a `slug` which will be used for your URL base, provided `has_archive` is set to true. In this case you can use the `archive-{slug}.php` file to style the archive.

If you want to use a custom page instead, `has_archive` has to be `false` but then there's no reliable way to identify this "fake parent" from the single CPT post.

The best option is to introduce a configuration setting on a custom settings page the allows the user to select which page to use for the CPT's archive. In the breadcrumbs generation you'd then use this config value instead of hardcoding or URL string manipulation etc.

Your CPT:

```
register_post_type('cars', [
    'labels'              => [
        'name'            => 'Cars',
        'singular_name'   => 'Car'
    ],
    'supports'            => ['title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions'],
    'taxonomies'          => ['category', 'post_tag'],
    'public'              => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'has_archive'         => false,
    'rewrite'             => ['slug' => 'cars']
]);
```

After you change settings that affect rewrite rules, go to Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks page and click save to rebuild the cache.

Comment: Hi, okey thanks. But if i would like to have an wysiwyg editor to add content to archive page, how do i achieve that?

Comment: That gets tricky. You could create "special" post or page or a new CPT just for special content and pull it by post ID into the `archive-cars.php` file. You could also create a special theme settings page in dashboard for "extra" content. Or you could set `'has_archive' => false` and add in the page like you had before but then you need to do a custom WP query in that page's template to pull in the posts.

Comment: I see I missed the bit about `/cars/` having to be a normal page. In this case `has_archive` needs to be `false`, as for breadcrumbs, there's no way to reliably identify the "fake parent" page's slug from the single cars page. The most reliable would be to grab the current permalink and do string manipulation to cut off the last path part.

Comment: Thank you crean for that answer, i suspected this but i wanted to see if anyone else had a solution to this.